# Query for specific subdocuments in MongoDB/Morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia, querying, nosql

I have a document stored in MongoDB that looks something like this:

```
{ '_id' : 'XXX', 'myProps' : [ { '_id' : 'YYY', 'propA' : 'ValueA' }, { '_id' : 'ZZZ', 'propA' : 'ValueB' } ] }
```

I'm using Morphia to model this into Java objects.  What I would like to do is query for elements within `myProps` that have a `propA` value of `'ValueA'`.  Is this possible?  Is it possible to query for specific values within a subdocument?  I've tried using queries like:

```
myProps.propA == 'ValueA'
```

...but, I still see all values of `myProps` being returned.  Is there something I'm missing in my query?  Or is it not possible to make such a query using Morphia/MongoDB?

**UPDATE**:  My code thus far...

My entity and embedded classes:

```
@Entity
public class MyTestClass implements Serializable {

   @Id
   private ObjectId id;

   @Embedded
   private List<MyProps> myProps;

   ...

}

@Embedded
public class MyProps {

  private String propA;

  ...

}
```

I have created the appropriate DAO class for it by extending BasicDAO.  Here is my query:

```
Query<MyTestClass> q = this.myTestClassDAO.createQuery();
q.field("myProps.propA").qual("ValueA");

MyTestClass result = q.get();
```

The code executes correctly, but when I look at `result.getMyProps()` I see a list containing ALL of the `myProps` values, not just the ones with `propA == 'ValueA'`.

Comment: Can you show the code you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Using the fluent interface it should be something like `field("myProps.propA").equal("ValueA").field("myProps.propA").notEqual("ValueB")`.

Comment: As you can see in the code I posted above, that's what I'm trying.  However, I'm still seeing ALL values of myProps being returned in my entity class.

Comment: 1) I assume ``.qual(`` is just a typo. Be sure not to use ``.equals(``, which is a common error. 2) Wait, what are you trying to get? You will get all the complete documents with any match for ``myProps.propA == ValueA``. If you only want to get specific fields, use ``.retrievedFields(``

Comment: Yes, just a typo.  Sorry.  I want to get all values of myProps that have propA == ValueA.  That is, I DON'T want any with propA == ValueB.

Comment: I've updated the query above to explicitly exclude values of ``ValueB``

Comment: That's fine, but what about if there is ValueC, ValueD, etc.?  Is there a general-purpose solution for this?

Comment: You can use ``.hasNoneOf(`` to add ValueB, ValueC,... but you will somehow need to list them. If that's not really possible, you'll need to change your schema somehow